# Some subcategories not showing in dropdown menu (OpenCart)

Tags: drop-down-menu, opencart, categories

Some of my subcategories are not showing in the dropdown menus. All the settings are the same for all of my subcategories.

All seo-keywords are unique and I have one product in those subcategories.
Live example: http://www.azores-store.com/a-teline

The category A-teline has two subcategories (A-teline 50x70 and A-teline 70x100)
They show on the navigation bar on the left but they won't show up as a dropdown menu on the top navigation bar (like categories Mainostekstiilit and Roll Up)

I have tried deleting browser cache and tried both Chrome and Firefox.

Here is the part of the code in header.tpl that handles the menu:

```html
<?php if ($categories) { ?>
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
      <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
      <div>
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($category['children']);) { ?>
        <ul>
          <?php $j = $i + ceil(count($category['children']) / $category['column']); ?>
          <?php for (; $i < $j; $i++) { ?>
          <?php if (isset($category['children'][$i])) { ?>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['children'][$i]['name']; ?></a></li>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php } ?>
        </ul>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Silly question, but isn't it possible that the main (top) navigation is *hard-coded* into the (header) template? Maybe posting the code for your top navigation rendering would be useful...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Nope, it's not hard-coded. I will add the part of the code in the question.

Comment: I disabled vqmod and refreshed the page and they appeared in the dropdown menu! So now I know it's some of the vqmod's that is causing this trouble.

Comment: Good point. Now enable vQmod and turn off all the extensions, then start turning them on one by one. The one which after turning on causes the categories to disappear will need some deeper examination ;-)

Comment: The file that was causing it was "vqmod_opencart_turbo_lite_1.1.xml"
To my knowledge it affects the caching but I don't know why it blocked the new subcategories from showing even though I deleted my browser cache and vqcache folder

Comment: Maybe this caching extension has it's own cache repository that You need to refresh as well ;-)

Comment: I had to empty the folder "system/cache" as well. I only emptied the vqcache folder at first :)

Comment: Well, normally when you edit/add/remove a category (product, info page, manufacturer, currency, language, etc.) **via administration** the corresponding cache file(s) should be automatically deleted and after the frontend is refreshed the cache file is re-created. If You have some (third-party) importers or if You are editing entries in DB manually, make sure that the corresponding cache files are deleted afterwards.

Comment: I think the vqmod somehow changes that procedure. I did them all from the admin panel and not directly the DB :) but it's sorted now.

Comment: hi shadyyx @ shadyyx